# What is the best way to get these timers under control?

Tags: javascript

I've inherited this code and have been playing with it for quite some time.  I have it working now the first time through the countdown, but after the first session refresh I believe I still have a second and maybe third timer running.  I'm sure I need to implement clearInterval() to keep this on a solid 20 minute timer but I'm just not sure how to do this properly.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var DoLogout = 1;
    var WarnMills;
    var TimeoutMills;
    var WarnDurationMills;
    var RedirectURL;
    var _timeLeft;

    function StartTimeout(TimeoutValue, WarnValue, WarnDuration, URLValue) {
        TimeoutMills = TimeoutValue;
        WarnMills = WarnValue;
        WarnDurationMills = WarnDuration;
        RedirectURL = URLValue;
        setTimeout(UserTimeout, TimeoutMills);
        setTimeout(WarnTimeout, WarnMills);
    }

    function UserTimeout() {
        if (DoLogout == 1) {
            top.location.href = RedirectURL;
        }
        else {
            DoLogout = 1;
            setTimeout(UserTimeout, TimeoutMills);
            setTimeout(WarnTimeout, WarnMills);
        }
    }

    function WarnTimeout() {
        _timeLeft = (WarnDurationMills / 1000);
        updateCountDown();
        $find('mdlSessionTimeout').show();
    }

    function updateCountDown() {
        var min = Math.floor(_timeLeft / 60);
        var sec = _timeLeft % 60;
        if (sec < 10)
            sec = "0" + sec;

        document.getElementById("CountDownHolder").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

        if (_timeLeft > 0) {
            _timeLeft--;
            setTimeout(updateCountDown, 1000);
        }
        else {


            window.location.replace("AdminLogin.aspx");

        }

        if (_timeLeft < (5 * 60)) {
            $find('mdlSessionTimeout').show();
        }
    }

    function PreserveSession() {
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SessionKeepAlive.asmx/Check",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: checkAuthenticatedOk,
            error: checkAuthenticatedError
        });

    }        
}

function checkAuthenticatedOk() {
    DoLogout = 0;
    _timeLeft = (20 * 60);
    TimeoutMills = (20 * 60 * 1000);
    $find('mdlSessionTimeout').hide();
}

function checkAuthenticatedError() {
    window.location.replace("AdminLogin.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You can push the `timer ids` into an array and retrieve them when necessary or even clear all timers by looping over the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a StartTimeout, make sure that the previous timer has first been cleared.

```
var userTimeoutId, warnTimeoutId;
function StartTimeout(...){
    ...
    clearTimeout(userTimeoutId);
    clearTimeout(warnTimeoutId);
    userTimeoutId = setTimeout(UserTimeout, TimeoutMills);
    warnTimeoutId = setTimeout(WarnTimeout, WarnMills);
}
```

Write similar code under userTimeout function too.

Comment: I tried your answer, and added the clearTimeout to the userTimeout function as well, and the countdown went from 14 minutes to 5 minutes in one tick.  Any other ideas?